# Connect-ServiceFabricCluster call fails when called twice

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am working on creating a script that I can use to deploy my Azure Service Fabric Application to my local cluster or to a Azure hosted cluster.  And I am running into an issue if I run the script twice.  The `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` command fails when my script is executed the second time.  I can restart the PowerShell console, or PowerShell ISE and the issue is not seen again until the second call.  This results in a cumbersome process to change the script.

```
function Read-XmlElementAsHashtable
{
    Param (
        [System.Xml.XmlElement]
        $Element
    )

    $hashtable = @{}
    if ($Element.Attributes)
    {
        $Element.Attributes | 
            ForEach-Object {
                $boolVal = $null
                if ([bool]::TryParse($_.Value, [ref]$boolVal)) {
                    $hashtable[$_.Name] = $boolVal
                }
                else {
                    $hashtable[$_.Name] = $_.Value
                }
            }
    }

    return $hashtable
}

function Read-PublishProfile
{
    Param (
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [String]
        $PublishProfileFile
    )

    $publishProfileXml = [Xml] (Get-Content $PublishProfileFile)
    $publishProfile = @{}

    $publishProfile.ClusterConnectionParameters = Read-XmlElementAsHashtable $publishProfileXml.PublishProfile.Item("ClusterConnectionParameters")
    $publishProfile.UpgradeDeployment = Read-XmlElementAsHashtable $publishProfileXml.PublishProfile.Item("UpgradeDeployment")

    if ($publishProfileXml.PublishProfile.Item("UpgradeDeployment"))
    {
        $publishProfile.UpgradeDeployment.Parameters = Read-XmlElementAsHashtable $publishProfileXml.PublishProfile.Item("UpgradeDeployment").Item("Parameters")
        if ($publishProfile.UpgradeDeployment["Mode"])
        {
            $publishProfile.UpgradeDeployment.Parameters[$publishProfile.UpgradeDeployment["Mode"]] = $true
        }
    }

    $publishProfileFolder = (Split-Path $PublishProfileFile)
    $publishProfile.ApplicationParameterFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($PublishProfileFolder, $publishProfileXml.PublishProfile.ApplicationParameterFile.Path)

    return $publishProfile
}

$profileSettings = Read-PublishProfile $PublishProfileFile

try
{
    $clusterConnectionParameters = $profileSettings.ClusterConnectionParameters
    [void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @clusterConnectionParameters)
}
catch [System.Fabric.FabricObjectClosedException]
{
    Write-Warning "Service Fabric cluster may not be connected."
    throw
}
```

If you've looked into the `Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1` script that Visual Studio creates when you create an Azure Service Fabric Application, this code should look familiar as that is my source for what I used in my script.

The error message I see when I run the script a second time is:

```
WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
WARNING: Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
WARNING: Service Fabric cluster may not be connected.
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : One or more errors occurred.
At MyScript.ps1:218 char:9
+     [void](Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @clusterConnectionParameters)
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster
```

My Local.xml Publish Profile, I've made no changes to it, it is the default file Visual Studio created when I create the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublishProfile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/05/fabrictools">
  <ClusterConnectionParameters />
  <ApplicationParameterFile Path="..\ApplicationParameters\Local.xml" />
</PublishProfile>
```

Steps I take when I see the issue:

1. Run script to deploy
2. Verify everything is working
3. Reset local cluster
4. Run script to deploy again
5. Script encounters error

I do not see this issue when connecting multiple times to a cluster in Azure, only when connected to my local cluster.

Is there anything I missing as to not encounter the issue on a second run?  I wonder if I'm missing a disconnect command as a restart would clear any state that is kept around, but I've not found anything that appears to be a disconnect from service fabric cluster command.

I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587940/connect-servicefabriccluster-fails-to-contact-naming-server-on-remote-azure-serv) as well on SO which appears to be the same error, but the path to reproduce the issue is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this I specified the ConnectionEndpoint in my Local.xml Publish Profile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublishProfile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/05/fabrictools">
  <ClusterConnectionParameters ConnectionEndpoint="localhost:19000" />
  <ApplicationParameterFile Path="..\ApplicationParameters\Local.xml" />
</PublishProfile>
```